# Apache2 + mod_proxy: Add custom response header if request is handled by backend server

Tags: proxy, apache2

Is it possible to set a custom response header like

`Header set PROXY_BACKEND "true" env=HAVE_VERBOSE`

if the request was forwarded to the backend server? If yes, how?

I have a few caching directives which would not set this header, as the expected output.

One option I have is setting the header on the backend servers itself, but it would be easier if I can configure this on my proxy server directly for all domains needed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/154641/2172543 ?

Comment: @Marcel Nope, I found this post too. The difference is, that in your link the question is: How can I inject a request header to the backend? I want the proxy to set a response header IF the request was handled by the backend server, else not. For example, I have an alias defined to provide images from local proxy disk, but php request should be handled by the backend servers and i want to see if the configuration works by usage of response headers.